# How do I import Bootstrap in ES6 for a react project?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How can I import the bootstrap js library so that I can use it with jQuery in ES6?
I am looking for the one that uses the keyword "import" instead of "require"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Write the following statement in a console:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Write this in your code:

```
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

Comment: can u elaborate ? so will I be able to use the js function from bootstrap via jQuery?

Comment: While your post may answer the question, it is difficult for someone who does not know how to solve the problem to solve it from the information that you give.  Please elaborate so that the OP better understands the answer - [From LQP Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11148875)